# Is there any possibilities to add a tabStyle prop for each icon in material top tab navigator from React Navigation 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, icons, tabbar

So, here is a piece of my code:

```
tabBarOptions={{
   style: styles.topTabbar,
   renderIndicator: () => null,
   iconStyle: styles.iconStyle,
   showLabel: false,
   pressColor: "#FDF5F1",
   showIcon: true,
   scrollEnabled: true,
   tabStyle: {
      width: 100,
      borderWidth: 1
   }
}}
```

Here I assign the tabStyle prop and width for it. It works for every element of my tabbar, but I need to do set a different width for every component. How can I do so in React Navigation 5?

Answer (score 0):

I use material-top-navigator bar v6.x
to set the width of each label with the following styles:
in <Tab.Navigator> set the baritemstyle width with 'auto'

```
tabBarItemStyle: {
  width:'auto',
}
```

Then you can set the width of each label in screen tag:

```
<Tab.Screen name="Chats" component={ChatsScreen}
                options={{                        
                    tabBarLabelStyle: { width: labelWidth },                         
                }}/>
```

**The width of the camera tab is 50, while others are about 100:**

[image: The width of the camera tab is 50, while others are about 100]

Answer (score -1):

Just write so:

```
tabStyle1: {
      width: 100,
      borderWidth: 1
}

tabStyle2: {
          width: 100,
          borderWidth: 1
    }

tabStyle3: {
          width: 100,
          borderWidth: 1
    }
```

and so on. Numeral written after tabStyle prop depends on what icon do you need to change